# SWIG convert C-Pointer stringvalue to tcl string

Tags: c, tcl, swig, c-strings

because of my limited knowledge in C and SWIG i couldn't manage to adopt any public example for converting c-pointer chars to tcl strings  ....
I always get stuck at the problem that my tcl variable just doesn't get dereferenced 
like this :

tcl_str = _30e84c05ef550000_p_stringout2

string_pointer.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "string_pointer.h"

stringout2  Itla_Get_Model_Version (int laser, char * mv_string)
   {
       stringout2 * pointer2;       
       char *mod_ver ="PPCL600";
       pointer2 = malloc( sizeof(stringout2) );
       pointer2-> modelvers= *mod_ver;
       printf ( "Itla_Get_Model_Version : read   %s   \n",  mod_ver );
       return  *pointer2 ;
   }
```

string_pointer.h

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>


typedef struct {
      char      * modelvers;
} stringout2;

stringout2  Itla_Get_Model_Version   (int laser, char * mv_string) ;
```

string_pointer.swig

```
/* File : string_pointer.swig */
%module string_pointer

%{
#include "string_pointer.h"
%}

%include "typemaps.i"
%include "cpointer.i"
%include "cstring.i"

%typemap(argout) char* (char tmp) %{
    $1 = &tmp;
%}

stringout2  Itla_Get_Model_Version    (int laser, char *OUTPUT) ;

%include "string_pointer.h"
```

test.tcl

```
load ./string_pointer.so

proc test { laser  } {

scan [Itla_Get_Model_Version $laser ] %s  a 
puts "$a "
return $a
}

set name [test 1 ]
puts "Itla_Get_Model_Version= $name"
```

when executing the tcl-script you get :

```
Itla_Get_Model_Version : read   PPCL600 
_f0a759f8d9550000_p_stringout2 
Itla_Get_Model_Version= _f0a759f8d9550000_p_stringout2
```

so i finally need to dereference the Pointer to its value ...
But i don't know how to succeed.....

The C-function is given and can't be modified !

Anybody out there, knowing how to do it ?

Comment: That C function, `Itla_Get_Model_Version`, has a ***guaranteed memory leak*** in it as written. It _cannot_ be correct!

Comment: you are right... i might have reduced the function too much for this example..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your strings are basically ASCII or UTF-8, all you need to do is to tell SWIG that your function has allocated the string it is returning. For details see, [the SWIG docs](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Library_nn8) on C strings.

<sub>*yourcode.c*</sub>

```c
char *Itla_Get_Model_Version (int laser, char * mv_string) {
    // I assume this is a proxy for something more complicated...
    const char *mod_ver ="PPCL600";
    size_t len = strlen(mod_ver) + 1;

    char *output = malloc(len);
    memcpy(output, mod_ver, len);
    printf ( "Itla_Get_Model_Version : read   %s   \n",  mod_ver );
    return output;
}
```

<sub>*yourcode.h*</sub>

```c
char *Itla_Get_Model_Version(int laser, char * mv_string);
```

<sub>*yourcode.swig*</sub>

```c
/* Tell SWIG that this function returns something to be freed */
%newobject Itla_Get_Model_Version

/* And now we can use the standard C header */
%include "yourcode.h"
```

### If the above simple solution doesn't work…

Things get a lot more complicated if you are using a different encoding for your strings or if you wrap them inside a structure (as you did in your question). That's when you need a [typemap](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Typemaps), particularly ones of the [Tcl variety](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Tcl_nn36). Correctly writing a typemap depends on understanding the semantics of the values that you are producing and/or consuming *and* the semantics of the language that you're using. Assuming you want the wrapping, here's a *very* simple output typemap that *might* work:

```
%typemap(out) stringout2* {
    Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_NewStringObj($1->modelvers, -1));
    free($1);
}
```

Your function also *needs* to be modified to return a `stringout2*` by doing `return pointer2;`, and not a `stringout2` since otherwise you *will* be leaking memory on every call. You *can* return a `stringout2`, but if you are doing that then you should *not* allocate it with `malloc`, but rather keep it as a structure directly in a local variable.

In that case, the typemap you'd use is:

```
%typemap(out) stringout2 {
    Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_NewStringObj($1.modelvers, -1));
}
```

<sup>(Note the different type, different access to the field, and lack of `free`.)</sup>
And your structure should be declared as containing a `const char *` if it really is that.

---

If you have strings in a different encoding (and it isn't ISO 8859-1, for which you can cheat and use a binary string using `Tcl_NewByteArrayObj`; that's also what you want for slabbing a chunk of binary data over) then you'll need to write a typemap using `Tcl_ExternalToUtfDString`, and the amount of boilerplate code goes up. Tcl *insists* that its internal strings are in (almost) UTF-8, and ASCII is OK too as that's a strict subset; everything else *must* be converted.

Ask another question if that's what you need. You probably are either dealing with ASCII or binary data, so I'll leave (quite a bit more complex!) encoding conversion alone until requested.

Comment: FWIW, I don't use SWIG; it defaults to producing APIs that really don't feel like Tcl code.  I prefer to write the boilerplate by hand and get an integration that feels more natural. However, I can understand not wanting to do that with a large API.

Comment: If you're building a description of a more complex structure type, consider converting it to a list or dictionary on the Tcl side. See `Tcl_ListObjAppendElement` and `Tcl_DictObjPut` for the sorts of manipulators you need.